# Android RecycleView how to disable manual scroll but allow item clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an idea, which is make a RecyclerView auto scrolling but allow user to click item without stop scrolling.

First, I create a custom LayoutManager to disable manual scroll, also change the speed of scroll to a certain position

```
class CustomLayoutManager(context: Context, countOfColumns: Int) :
GridLayoutManager(context, countOfColumns) {

// Custom smooth scroller
private val smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
    override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float =
        500f / displayMetrics.densityDpi
}

// Disable manual scroll
override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean = false

// Using custom smooth scroller to control the duration of smooth scroll to a certain position
override fun smoothScrollToPosition(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    state: RecyclerView.State?,
    position: Int
) {
    smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
}
}
```

Then I do the initial work for the RecyclerView and start smooth scroll after 1 sec

```
viewBinding.list.apply {
        // initial recycler view
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        customLayoutManager = CustomLayoutManager(context = context, countOfColumns = 2)
        layoutManager = customLayoutManager

        // data list
        val dataList = mutableListOf<TestModel>()
        repeat(times = 100) { dataList.add(TestModel(position = it, clicked = false)) }

        // adapter
        testAdapter =
            TestAdapter(clickListener = { testAdapter.changeVhColorByPosition(position = it) })
        adapter = testAdapter
        testAdapter.submitList(dataList)

        // automatically scroll after 1 sec
        postDelayed({ smoothScrollToPosition(dataList.lastIndex) }, 1000)
    }
```

Everything goes as my expected until I found that the auto scrolling stopped when I clicked on any item on the RecycelerView, the function when `clickListener` triggered just change background color of the view holder in `TestAdapter`

```
fun changeVhColor(position: Int) {
    position
        .takeIf { it in 0..itemCount }
        ?.also { getItem(it).clicked = true }
        ?.also { notifyItemChanged(it) }
}
```

here is the screen recording [screen recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FWrneieKCDMVz4bhkslfbD4H5LTeJv1I/view?usp=sharing)

issues I encounter

1. auto scrolling stopped when I tap any item on the ReycelerView
2. first tap make scrolling stopped, second tap trigger `clickListener`, but I expect to trigger `clickListener` by one tap

Can anybody to tell me how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried several ways, found that the key of keep recycler view scrolling automatically is override `onInterceptTouchEvent`

Example

```
class MyRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
     context: Context,
     attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
     defStyle: Int = 0
 ) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
     override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean = false
}
```

that will make the custom RecyclerView ignore all touch event

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here. You should suspect the touch handling of the *RecyclerView* and, maybe, the call to `notifyItemChanged(it)`, but I believe that the *RecyclerView* is behaving correctly. You can look into overriding the touch code in the *RecyclerView* to make it do what you want - assuming you can get to it and override it.

An alternative would be to overlay the *RecyclerView* with another view that is transparent and capture all touches on the transparent view. You can then write code for the transparent view that interacts with the *RecyclerView* in the way that meets your objectives. This will also be tricky and you will have to make changes to the *RecyclerView* as it is constantly layout out views as scrolling occurs. Since you have your own layout manager, this might be easier if you queue changes to occur pre-layout as scrolling occurs.